# Why is the transition to increase the min-width of the button not working?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

When the search icon with `class ="click"` gets clicked
The class 'show-bar' is added to the classList of the div container with class 'search'
In CSS I selected the button with class="button" to increase its min-width from none to 5vw:
`transition: m in-width 0.35s ease-in` But it doesn't work

```js
const searchContainer = document.querySelector('.search');
const selectI = document.querySelector('.click');

// add class to button so that when clicked it shows the
const addOrRemove = () =>{
    if(searchContainer.classList =='search'){
        searchContainer.classList.add('show-bar');
    } else{
        searchContainer.classList.remove('show-bar');
    }
}

selectI.addEventListener('click', addOrRemove);
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: none;
    font-size:23px;
}

body{
    min-height:100vh;
    background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #7d5fff, #7158e2) ;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}

.search button{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding:11px 16px 11px 16px;
    background-color:#fafafa;
    cursor:pointer;
    min-width:none;
}

.search button:focus{
    outline:none;
}

.search.show-bar button{
    transition: min-width 0.35s ease-in;
    min-width:5vw;
    margin:auto;
}

.search button input{
    display:none;
    outline:none;
}

.search.show-bar button input{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hidden Search</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="search">
        <button class="button">
            <input placeholder= 'Search...'>
            <i class=" click fas fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi BenziBox, can you explain why you are using the input element inside of the button element?

Comment: As @novonimo mentioned it's weird (and not good for accessibility) to put an input inside a button. You should move the input outside the button, put the transition on `div.search`, and fade in the `input` on a delay after the div expands. I can't write it out right now but hopefully that gets you started.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure a min-width transition makes much sense.
Besides I would avoid activating the click of the icon but I would activate the click on the entire button.
I would try to do so:

```js
const searchContainer = document.querySelector('.search');
const selectI = document.querySelector('.button');

// add class to button so that when clicked it shows the
const addOrRemove = () =>{
    if(searchContainer.classList =='search'){
        searchContainer.classList.add('show-bar');
    } else{
        searchContainer.classList.remove('show-bar');
    }
}

selectI.addEventListener('click', addOrRemove);
```

```css
*{
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-style: none;
    font-size:23px;
}

body{
    min-height:100vh;
    background-image:linear-gradient(90deg, #7d5fff, #7158e2) ;
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
}

.search {
    width: 51px;
    position: relative;
    height: 51px;
}
.click.fa-search{
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
}

.search.show-bar {
    width: 300px;
    transition: right 2s, width 2s;
    height: 51px;
}
.search button{
    display:flex;
    justify-content:space-between;
    align-items: center;
    padding:11px 16px 11px 16px;
    background-color:#fafafa;
    cursor:pointer;
    min-width:none;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}

.search button:focus{
    outline:none;
}

.search.show-bar button{
    transition: min-width 0.35s ease-in;
    min-width:5vw;
    margin:auto;
}

.search button input{
    display:none;
    outline:none;
}

.search.show-bar button input{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hidden Search</title>
    <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.14.0/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-1PKOgIY59xJ8Co8+NE6FZ+LOAZKjy+KY8iq0G4B3CyeY6wYHN3yt9PW0XpSriVlkMXe40PTKnXrLnZ9+fkDaog==" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="script.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="search">
        <button class="button">
            <input placeholder= 'Search...'>
            <i class=" click fas fa-search"></i></button>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```